# y = x^25 -- How to solve for x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Something that never came in algebra class. Let $y = x^{25}$. If I were to solve for x would that then be $x = \sqrt[25]{y}$

Comment: Yes, indeed....

Comment: Unless you consider complex numbers.  Its like $x^2=1\implies x=\pm1$.

Comment: They always covered squares and cubes in class but nothing higher. I thought this might be the case but couldn't find anything on the web except pages covering squares and cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Note that then we would have $x^{25} = \left( \sqrt[25]{y} \right)^{25} = y$ as expected.